# WPF VB.NET ListView DataTemplate change

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview, layout

I'm trying to replicate the functionality you have in Windows Explorer for changing layout via a series of layout toggle buttons. Layouts such as "List", "Details", "Tiles", etc etc.

I've found several other posts on this, but none have really answered the problem for me, plus they are all C# and I've not used C# so trying to decipher the answers is extremely frustrating.

This is what I've got so far - I'm starting with just List and Details while trying to get is working, but plan to add in Tiles and Content as well:

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="List_Template">
        <Grid...>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Details_Template">
        <Grid...>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectedItem_Template">
        <Grid...>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="List_ContainerStyle">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource List_Template}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SelectedItem_Template}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="Details_ContainerStyle">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Details_Template}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SelectedItem_Template}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

I'm using Radio buttons to change the layout for simplicity at the moment, but will at some point change them to buttons that resemble the Windows Explorer options:

```
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <RadioButton x:Name="List_RadioButton" Content="List" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="8,0,8,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     Foreground="{DynamicResource LightFont_Colour}"
                     IsChecked="True"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="Details_RadioButton" Content="Details" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="8,0,8,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     Foreground="{DynamicResource LightFont_Colour}"
                     IsChecked="False"/>
        </Grid>
```

The ListView is Data Bound to a view from SQL Server. by default i want it to be on List layout if not manually set by the user:

```
    <Grid x:Name="Grid_Body" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView x:Name="DataList_ListView" 
                  Grid.Row="0" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedValuePath="ID"
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                  DataContext="{Binding}"
                  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource List_ContainerStyle}"
                  Background="{DynamicResource WhiteBackground_90Transparent}" Margin="0,0,0,0">

        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

VB.NET - I've been trying to find a way to change the ItemContainerStyle in code when i hit the RadioButton to change to details layout or back to list layout. The below does not work and was partially lifted from another stackoverflow post:

```
Private Sub List_RadioButton_Checked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles List_RadioButton.Checked
    CaseList_ListView.ItemContainerStyle = DirectCast(Resources("List_ContainerStyle"), System.Windows.Style)
End Sub

Private Sub Details_RadioButton_Checked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Details_RadioButton.Checked
    CaseList_ListView.ItemContainerStyle = DirectCast(Resources("Details_ContainerStyle"), System.Windows.Style)
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not only the ItemContainerStyle that changes, but also the ItemsPanel and probably also the ItemTemplate. It might be a lot simpler to replace the entire ListView.

Comment: I've found a solution to this, but I've not finished implementing it. Once I have, I'll answer the question with an example for future reference.